# What's wrong this code in Matlab: numeric::solve(x^6 - PI*x^2 = sin(3), x)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm new to Matlab and I'm attempting to use it to solve equations numerically. I consulted the Matlab documentation, found the following code:

`numeric::solve(x^6 - PI*x^2 = sin(3), x)`

I tried to execute it, but Matlab says:

```
numeric::solve(x^6 - PI*x^2 = sin(3), x)
         |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

I'm confused. Could you tell me what's wrong? I'm using Matlab R2013a on OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
syms x
sol_x = solve(x^6 - pi*x^2 == sin(3), x);
sol_x = sym2poly(sol_x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to use a command that only works in the MuPAD Notebook Interface in MATLAB. The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-solve.html) got better over time pointing this out. Does 2013a include the `vpasolve` command? If yes, that is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: According to the [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/release-notes.html#bti4vnc-1), [`vpasolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012b/symbolic/vpasolve.html) was added in R2012b.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you typed "solve" and "matlab" into Google and came across [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-solve.html). Note the warning in the yellow box at the top of the page that @ChristopherCreutzig alluded to in his answer. [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html) is a separate environment available to Matlab users – type `mupad` in your command window and you'll be able to run your command – but its functions are not directly callable from within Matlab. Many (if not most) of the functions in the [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html) use the MuPAD engine under the hood. In your case you can call `numeric::solve` from within Matlab like this:

```
syms x;
s = feval(symengine, 'numeric::solve', x^6 - sym(pi)*x^2 == sin(3), x)
```

or using the older string format:

```
s = feval(symengine, 'numeric::solve', 'x^6 - pi*x^2 = sin(3)', 'x')
```

The output of either can then be converted to double precision column vector with `s = double(s.')`. However, in this case there seems to be no reason not to use [`sym/solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) instead:

```
syms x
s = double(solve(x^6 - sym(pi)*x^2 == sin(3), x).');
```

See [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html) for further details and other options for calling MuPAD functions from within Matlab.